# Merging two github accounts

Tags: git, github

Let's say I am having two github accounts `xyz` (Mail Id - `xyz@xyz.com`) and `abc` (`abc@abc.com`). `xyz` account I use for doing all my work related commits. `xyz@xyz.com` is the mail account of the organization for which I work for. I use `abc` account for all my other personal work.

I am finding it little annoying to maintain both the accounts. Is there a way I can merge both the accounts and have one github account `abc`. All the commits that I do in my organization's private repo, the communication regarding that should come to my `xyz` email id. But all public work that I do in github the communication for that should come to my `abc` email id.

Github also suggests to maintain only account as mentioned in [this](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-multiple-user-accounts/) link.

Can you please let me know if it is possible to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to merge the two accounts when in reality you want to distinguish ownership/contribution.   Wouldn't you risk litigation with your employer (i.e. he sees your non-work commits and claims you do non-work tasks during your work time), or loose ownership (if employer claims your work account) ?

Comment: There is no risk of litigation with my employer. I am not clear about your ownership query, how can they claim my git account?

Comment: Because [github pricing](https://github.com/pricing) is per user (as you seem to use a private repo), and if your employer pays for it, he might under certain circumstances have some [rights](http://www.weil.com/articles/establishing-employers-ownership-in-social-media).  I'm not a legal expert, but I think that the big advantage of keeping accounts separated is that you clearly distinguish what's done for work for your employer and paid by him, and what belongs to yourself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that question should be directed to GitHub support

Comment: I don't think that this is a valid reason to vote a question as off-topic. Just because something can be asked to Github support does not mean that it can not be asked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transfer ownership of all your repositories from each of their settings tab. It requires you to type the full name of the repo, the username transferring to, and then the user has to accept the transfer. Once you have transferred everything, as a bonus, Github will continue to even redirect the old repository url's to the new repo. Then you can either close the old account or simply stop using it.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question once I transfer the account what will happen to the emails? Is there a way I can configure all communications related to private repo go to my organizational email id?

Comment: Yes, once you transfer all repos to your organization's account, then that one will get all the email correspondence from Github. Don't forget to update your local git config do that each commit message also has your email identifier- but that won't effect Github system correspondence.

Answer (score 1):

The reply I got from github support:-

> Thanks for getting in touch!
>
> You can certainly merge the two accounts, and the article that you
>   mentioned contains instructions on what to do:
>
> https://help.github.com/articles/merging-multiple-user-accounts/
>
> "*Is there a way I can merge both the accounts and have one github*
>   *account `xyz`. All the commits that I do in my organization's private*
>   *repo, the communication regarding that should come to my `xyz@xyz.com`*
>   *email id. But all public work that I do in github the communication*
>   *for that should come to my `abc@abc.com` email id.*"
>
> I'm sorry but this won't be possible. There's no way to specify that
>   notifications for certain actions be sent to one email address, while
>   others are sent to a different address.
>
> Please let us know if you have any other questions!

Comment: It's possible to specify different e-mail addresses based on the "organizations". It's strange even GitHub employees don't know about it. Check Settings / Notifications / Custom routing.