# Merging GitHub accounts - contributions and stats

Tags: github

I want to merge my two GitHub accounts (meaning transferring repositories ownership to one account, and deleting the other, according to https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-a-repository/). Will my other account inherit the contributions number (and therefore contribution graph and activity overview) from my old account? In other words, what determines the number of contributions in a GitHub account: is it when the email address of the commit corresponds to one of the email adresses associated with my GitHub account?

I have read [Merging two github accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030809/merging-two-github-accounts) but it doesn't answer the number of contributions question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Transferred repos will inherit issues, pull request, contribution history, stars, watches.

The contribution history is a different story, and how it's calculated is explained here: https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-contributions-on-your-profile/ To quote from there:

> #### What counts as a contribution
>
> On your profile page, certain actions
>   count as contributions:
>
> - Committing to a repository's default branch or gh-pages branch
> - Opening an issue
> - Proposing a pull request
> - Submitting a pull request review
> - Co-authoring commits in a repository's default branch or gh-pages
>     branch

Assume you have 2 users: A `<a@gmail.com>`, B `<b@gmail.com>` and you're merging B into A:

- Events like "opening a PR", "opening an issue", "commenting on issue/PR", "making code review on a PR" which count as contribution on B's profile will be lost
- Events like "commits" on the master branch will be added to A –if you add `b@gmail.com` as one of your emails in A’s account settings

when you transfer B's repos to A, and then delete account B.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that you need to remove account B's email on that account before adding it to account A -- it will tell you "error adding ______: email is already in use" otherwise.