# Can I export stats from self-hosted GitLab profile to my public GitLab profile?

Tags: gitlab

We have self-hosted GitLab in our company. I want to export my activity statistics to my gitlab.com profile. Because now my regular profile looks like I didn't work for years, so I want to transfer all stats to here. Is it possible?

Comment: I found this [question related to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54262958/merging-github-accounts-contributions-and-stats) but I am not entirely sure if the same behavior will occur in GitLab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method to populate the graph by itself. The contribution graph is populated by activity.

Since contributions includes commits, you could partially do this by importing your projects since it should use the commit email to associate it to your user and the commit date to populate the graph.

This should be similar for issues and merge requests, if you import a project export (instead of only the repository).

As I assume you're talking about GitLab.com when talking about your "regular profile", the only caveat is that imported projects are associated with the person who imports the projects until [the related feature request is implemented](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/223137).